# Excel process remains alive when using Workbook.Cellls

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

after writing something in a cell of an existing excel file, the excel process in the background didn't close. If i comment out the section with worksheet.Cells[1,1]=2 then the excel process will disappear like expected.

Thx in advance for help.

Here is my code:

```
                Excel.Application exelApp = new Excel.Application();
                var workbooks = exelApp.Workbooks;
                Excel.Workbook workbook = null;

                workbook = workbooks.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


                var worksheets = workbook.Worksheets;
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)worksheets.get_Item("Einzelliste");

                //worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = 2;

                workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                workbooks.Close();
                exelApp.Quit();

                ReleaseObject(worksheet);                    
                ReleaseObject(worksheets);                                        
                ReleaseObject(workbook);                    
                ReleaseObject(workbooks);                                       
                ReleaseObject(exelApp);

                worksheet = null;
                worksheets = null;
                workbook = null;
                workbooks = null;
                exelApp = null;

    private static void ReleaseObject(object theObject)
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(theObject);
    }
```

Edit: According to the suggestion from Mark:

```
                var range =worksheet.get_Range("A1");
                range.Value = 1; ReleaseObject(range);
```

In contradiction to some suggestions that this post is a duplucated question: I have to say that it's not because all the objects were released correctly and there is no use of "double dots" in the source code. The suggested calls of Garbage Collector do not solve the problem either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly clean up Excel interop objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/158706/2140173)

Comment: `//worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = 2;` what if you changed it to 
`//worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = 2;`

Comment: @ Michal: I have read the post already, but it doesn't contain my problem.

Comment: @MethodMan: There is no definition for Value.

Comment: I also notice that you are not `Activating` the worksheet.. which may or may not be needed.. question, when you step through the code, what happens when you step into the code and past  this line `worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = 2;` when you uncomment it ..? does it raise and error or just hangup.. what happens when you use the Quick Watch to inspect `worksheet.Cells[1, 1];`

Comment: @MethodMan: Nothing happened when i passed the line worksheet.Cells[1,1]=2; The application didnt hang and the file was saved correctly. When i used Quick Watch i couldn't see anything special but some Reflection.TargetInvocationExeption with some COM properties. But i think it doesn't matter.

Comment: @BenjaminMartin so does this cause an actual problem with your running process..? even though you are calling the Marshal.ReleaseComObject method, I am thinking that the reference to it is being handled properly however the `Garbage Collector` does not remove it from the TaskManager immediately as you are probably expecting.. can you clarify on if this is truly causing an issue especially in regards to if you wanted to open the saved excel spread sheet after saving..

Comment: Instead of Interop, consider using a library like EPPlus and the Open XML SDK to read/update/generate `xlsx` files directly, without using Excel at all.

Comment: @Pnagiotis Kanavos: Yeah you are right, but using Open XML SDK has it's flaws especially in manipulating tables and charts. EPPlus is not compatible with Excel 2013 and furthermore the complexity of using Open XML SDK is tremendous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Range object to get access to cells or cell before manipulating it.  Then make sure you release the COM Object referencing the range. You also need to arrange your calls so that you release the COM Object right after you use it.  Try also save the changes in the Excel document, Excel might not be closing because it is waiting for a user response to save the file.

Additionally (although not required by the OP), never loop across the cells of Excel.  Prepare your data on an array of objects either for cells in a row or cells in a column.  Use array of arrays for a grid.  Then use the Range object to set the values.

Comment: the OP is correctly releasing the ComObject in the `ReleaseObject` method

Comment: @MethodMan, there is a hidden reference to the cells[1, 1] which has not been released.

Comment: I am thinking that there is an Indexing issue but I can't tell that is why I am waiting on the OP to respond with what the data is when debugging and using the `QuickWatch` to validate what the data is in `cells[1,1]` if any .

Answer (score 0):

Based on information provide in [this](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/asp-net-cant-kill-excel-exe-with-office-pia.123703/#post-528575) link, I think the cause of the problem may lie in the following line of code.

```
  Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)worksheets.get_Item("Einzelliste");
```

Just a guess, because it doesn't follow the rule in the link exactly, but I wonder if the cast does something funny with COM object.

The critical part of the link was:

> your problem is the line.
>
> Dim wkBook As Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls
>
> because .net needs wrapper to call com objects it really turns into
>
> Dim wkBook As Workbook dim tmp as WorkBooks tmp = xlApp.Workbooks
>   wkBook = tmp.Open("C:\test.xls
>
> the tmp variable has a com ref that will not be released until its
>   garabage collected. the rule you should use is never use 2 dots with
>   com objects. alway create a tmp, and call ReleaseComObject() on the
>   tmps.

Of course, your code doesn't have the exact same stuff, but I wonder if the cast might be causing some strange behavior behind the scenes.